# Identifying Interactions of certain values in a SQL Column

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables

CustomerTable

```
 CustomerID   |   Year_Date    |   Score    |   Tier   
-------------------------------------------------------------
      100     |      2014      |       50   |  Beginner
      100     |      2014      |       25   |  Naieve
      100     |      2014      |      100   |  Pro
      100     |      2014      |       60   |  Mediocre
      100     |      2014      |       70   |  Advanced
      100     |      2015      |       20   |  Poor
      100     |      2015      |        5   |  Unacceptable
      200     |      2015      |      100   |  Pro
      200     |      2015      |      150   |  SuperPro
      200     |      2015      |      180   |  Top
```

Interaction Table

```
TierInteraction   | AdditionalScore
----------------------------------
Pro_Advanced      |         75 
Beginner_Mediocre |         50
Pro_SuperPro      |         80
Pro_Top           |        100
Mediocre_Poor     |         10
Poor_Unacceptable |          5
```

Now, from the Tier column in Customer Table, I need to identify if any TierInteraction from InteractionTable exists

Example - 
The following interactions exist

For Customer 100 for year 2014

1. Pro_Advanced
2. Beginner_Mediocre

For Customer 100 for year 2015

1. Poor_Unacceptable

For Customer 200 for year 2015

1. Pro_SuperPro
2. Top_Pro

And Here's how I need the result table

Result Table

```
CustomerID | Year_Date | Score |   Tier       | TierInteraction   | AdditionalScore  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   100     | 2014      |  50   |  Beginner    | Beginner_Mediocre |    50
   100     | 2014      |  25   |  Naive       | NULL              |     0
   100     | 2014      | 100   |  Pro         | Pro_Advanced      |    75
   100     | 2014      |  60   |  Mediocre    | Beginner_Mediocre |    50
   100     | 2014      |  70   |  Advanced    | Pro_Advanced      |    75
   100     | 2015      |  20   |  Poor        | Poor_Unacceptable |     5
   100     | 2015      |   5   |  Unacceptable| Poor_Unacceptable |     5
   200     | 2015      | 100   |  Pro         | Pro_SuperPro      |    80
   200     | 2015      | 150   |  SuperPro    | Pro_SuperPro      |    80
   200     | 2015      | 180   |  Top         | Pro_Top           |   100
```

Business Rules:

- Interactions should be identified per customer per year
- One row can have multiple interactions with other rows.(Customer 200
  Pro interacts with SuperPro as well as Top) Additional score for
  both interactions should be accounted at least once.
- Order of Interaction does not matter. Pro_Advanced is same as Advanced_Pro

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do here. I would suggest this link as a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange, in fact for me this question was well done and I see no edits (at the moment)...

Comment: hmm...it wasn't me that voted to close. I wasn't able to get a clear picture but I'm glad that @Shnugo could.

Comment: @Shnugo - I tried your query but it always returned an out of memory exception error. The real challenge I am facing is adding the additional scores to a new column when certain values exist in a particular column. Could I altogether remove the Interaction table and write the query using a case statement ? Example - If a customer ID has Pro and Advanced Tier for a year the additional score should be 75.

Comment: I'll check this a little later ...

Comment: @AshayNirgude, please put your comments below the answer you are talking about, thx. I'll comment there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
declare @Customer TABLE(CustomerID INT,Year_Date INT, Score INT, Tier VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @customer VALUES   
(100,2014,50,'Beginner')
,(100,2014,25,'Naieve')
,(100,2014,100,'Pro')
,(100,2014,60,'Mediocre')
,(100,2014,70,'Advanced')
,(100,2015,20,'Poor')
,(100,2015,5,'Unacceptable')
,(200,2015,100,'Pro')
,(200,2015,150,'SuperPro')
,(200,2015,180,'Top');

declare @TierInteraction TABLE(TierInteraction VARCHAR(100),AdditionalScore INT);
insert into @TierInteraction VALUES
 ('Pro_Advanced',75)
,('Beginner_Mediocre',50)
,('Pro_SuperPro',80)
,('Pro_Top',100)
,('Mediocre_Poor',10)
,('Poor_Unacceptable',5);

WITH TierInteractionResolved AS
(
    SELECT ti.*
          ,tiParts.*
    FROM @TierInterAction AS ti
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<root><r>' +  REPLACE(ti.TierInteraction,'_','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML)) AS tiSplit(ti)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT tiSplit.ti.value('/root[1]/r[1]','varchar(max)') AS firstPart
              ,tiSplit.ti.value('/root[1]/r[2]','varchar(max)') AS secondPart
    ) AS tiParts
)
SELECT * 
FROM @Customer AS c
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM TierInteractionResolved AS tir
    WHERE (c.Tier=tir.firstPart AND EXISTS(SELECT x.* FROM @customer AS x WHERE tir.secondPart=x.Tier AND x.Year_Date=c.Year_Date))
       OR (c.Tier=tir.secondPart AND EXISTS(SELECT x.* FROM @customer AS x WHERE tir.firstPart=x.Tier AND x.Year_Date=c.Year_Date))

) AS FinalTiers
ORDER BY c.CustomerID,c.Year_Date
```

Comment: @Ashay Nirgude, is this the solution for you? If yes, please vote up and or mark as accepted, thx

Comment: I tried your query but it always returned an out of memory exception error. The real challenge I am facing is adding the additional scores to a new column when certain values exist in a particular column. Could I altogether remove the Interaction table and write the query using a case statement ? Example - If a customer ID has Pro and Advanced Tier for a year the additional score should be 75.

Comment: @AshayNirgude, I cannot imagin, that these lines produce any out of memory exceptions... If you take my code lines and past them in an empty query window, you should see the expected result...

Comment: @Shnugo- the table on which I am applying the logic contains of 30 million entries and though I can use a work around for memory error, the time to execute the query is over 40 mins

Comment: @AshayNirgude, this is important information you should have given earlier :-)   In this case you should think about a re-design. My code splits data like "Poor-Unacceptable" in two parts and uses these parts later on. This is **very** time consuming. You should put the two parts in separate fields: Your existing column is the "caption", and you need two more columns for the two parts. This should speed up a lot!